# Where does the "Subscribe to this feed" link on an RSS feed come from?

Tags: rss

Is this automatically generated by the browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, the web application on the server that provides browser with HTML pages also generates an XML file (RSS specification) based on the content of the web site. It can be styled so that it looks nice but most often you provide some RSS reader with the URL reference to the XML file and the reader displays it to you